# Why does 1 < 2 < 3 evaluate correctly, but 3 > 2 > 1 doesn't?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
: 1 < 2 < 3
true
: 3 > 2 > 1
false
...
...
: 3 > 2 && 2 > 1
true
```

Maybe I'm really over thinking things, but I would assume that they'd both evaluate to true. Why does it not?

Comment: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852056/why-does-alert321-alert-false)

Comment: Thanks haha ~ I knew it was something simple. This also answers why it would work "sometimes" (when the last case evaluated to `int(1)`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `1 < 2` evaluates as `true` which is less than `3`,
but `3 > 2` which also evaluates as `true` is NOT greater than `1`

Comment: (During `>` or `<` with a number, true is *converted* to 1).

Answer (score 3):

Because  `3 > 2` evaluates to `true` then `true > 1` evaluates to `1 > 1` which is `false`